# drop the duplicate columns with sas

Tags: sql, sas

Would the following code work?

I'm dropping duplcated columns from my tables. I feel a bit confused after thinking about it. My code looks like working but I'm concerned about unseen mistakes.

```
proc sql;
create table toto 
as select min(nomvar) as nomvar,count(intitule) as compte
from dicoat
group by intitule
having count(intitule) > 1;



data work.toto;
set toto;
    do while(cpte>=1);
    proc sql;
delete from dicoat where nomvar in (select nomvar from toto);
    insert into toto
select min(nomvar) as nomvar,count(intitule) as compte from dicoat
group by intitule
having count(intitule) > 1;
end;
 run;

data _null_;
file tempf;
set toto end=lastobs;
if _n_=1 then put "data aat;set aat (drop=";
put var /;
if lastobs then put ");run;";
run;

%inc tempf;

filename tempf clear;
```

Comment: This site is not a service for codereview, use http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: Thanks for your input , Manu. Reading the code, it should do the trick. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thoughts and some questioning (ok - lots of questionning), one of my acquaintance helped me out with this

```
proc sort data=dicoat;
    by title;
run;

data _null_;
     set dicoat end=last;
     length dropvar $1000;
     retain dropvar;
     by title;
     if not first.title then dropvar = catx(' ',dropvar,nomvar);
     if last then call symput('dropvar',trim(dropvar));
run;


data aat;
     set aat(drop=&DROPVAR.);
run;
```

It should do the tricks of removing duplicate columns. And no,`proc sql` does not work within a data step.

Best.